# In Python 3.7+, are dicts ordered when specifically created using curly brace notation ({})?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

In Python 3.7, dictionaries preserve insertion order. The `dict()` constructor, when provided with a list of tuples, will insert the keys in order.  Will curly brace notation also preserve order?  That is, will the below assertion always pass?

```
import random

keys = [str(i) for i in range(1_000_000)]

test_dict = {key: "" for key in keys}
assert keys == list(test_dict.keys())
```

I know this seems small, but I'm looking for specific documentation about the curly brace delimiter.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that `test_dict = {key: "" for key in keys}` is a dictionary comprehension, not a literal dict constructor.

Comment: Beside the point, but the curly braces aren't operators. I think they're classed as delimiters.

Comment: The question should not be whether `dict` and `{}` differ.  The question should be, "in what order are the keys inserted"?  I think you can convince yourself that the keys will be presented in the same order no matter how they are constructed.  Even doing them one at a time with a `for` loop will use the same insertion order.